# Inserting data from several arrays into respective fields in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, sql-insert

My code did work when I was using mysql, now upgrading to mysqli has introduced problems.  I have several interger arrays of various length and I am using a for loop of 48 steps to insert the data into the fields of my database.  What is happenning is my array that has only 4 elements is causing the whole database insert to stop after the 4 th loop. The process stops with a rejected URL request, which is my page presenting the insert commands.

My code:

```
$setcomm = array  (1201.30,16.30,3.22,7.98,0.95, 78.78, 54.12,1.45,3.09,62.44,36.95,269.64,
  239.59,6.15,4.57,.43,100.00,.8622,14640,    1.21,  1.55, 1.19,  1.16, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0.2125 );//dec30 2014

 $qk = array (1,1,1,1);


$xmports = array ( 777, 32197, 2534, 2124, 4658, 8943, 9214, 7360, 24020, 14689, 566, 2310, 00.00 ,3780, 10812, 2448, 262, 11557, 11171, 5711, 12740, 26850,  26551, 1818, 2615, 00.00, 00.00);

for($k=0;$k<48;$k++)

{   

$sqli = ( " INSERT INTO $mr (comm, qrt, trade, gross, interest, coffer) VALUES ( $setcomm[$k], $qk[$k], $xmports[$k], $GDP[$k], $bratz[$k], $fiscal[$k] )  ");



$stone=mysqli_query($connect2, $sqli);

}
```

Comment: Your array `$qk` has only 4 elements so when `$k` goes to 4 (zero based indexes) then accessing a non existent element will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have check your code. It looks fine. You must have to check one thing that is:-

- You are using three arrays as you mention in you question & array $qk having 4 elements. So can you make 'qrt' column default value
  NULL in your database under table structure. According to me after set
  default Null value for 'qrt' column it will working fine.

[image]

Set Default value like this in your database table. Please note it is just an example so if you know which fields always get a value for that there is no need to set Default Null Value.

Comment: yes, the answer to set qrt and other columns to NULL, I have tried INSERT INTO,  UPDATE SET but no success, can you give me an example on how to set mulitple columns to Null

Comment: $fixnull = ("UPDATE $mr SET comm = NULL, qrt = NULL, trade = NULL, gross = NULL, interest = NULL, coffer = NULL");

$setup = mysqli_query($connect7, $fixnull );

if (!$setup)
{ die('null set not working:' .mysqli_error()); }      this code gives no errors but my program is still stopping on fourth loop due to one column having only 4 entries.

Comment: @sonny I have added an image in my above answer please check that. If you already done this then can you please share your code so I can try to find what's the issue. I am happy to help you. Thanks !!